# Sequelize belongsToMany not creating new table

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Using sequelize, I expect this line:

```
m.User.belongsToMany(m.Company, {through: 'UserCompany'});
```

to generate a new table in my database called 'user_company' that would link the 'user' table and the 'company' table together.  However, it isn't doing that.  Am I misunderstanding the documentation when it says

> This will create a new model called UserProject with with the
>   equivalent foreign keys ProjectId and UserId. Whether the attributes
>   are camelcase or not depends on the two models joined by the table (in
>   this case User and Project).

or am I doing something wrong?

Here are the relations I am setting up

```
m.Company.hasMany(m.User);
m.User.belongsToMany(m.Company, {
    through: m.UserCompany
});

m.User.sync({force: true, match: /_test$/});
m.Company.sync({force: true, match: /_test$/});
m.UserCompany.sync({force: true, match: /_test$/});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I needed to create the UserCompany model manually.  So, UserCompany.js looks like:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

return sequelize.define('UserCompany', {

}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    paranoid: true
});

}
```

Then the belongsToMany automatically adds the correct columns to the table.

Comment: That should definitely not be necessary. Did you remember to call `sequelize.sync` after setting up the associations?

Comment: I am calling sync on each of the models.  Is that what you mean?  Or do you need to call sync on the sequelize object?  Maybe that is the problem.  I edited the original question to show how I am setting up the relations.

Comment: It looks like calling sync on the sequelize object did the trick, like you suggested.  Thanks!  One more question, if I need to add columns to the UserCompany table (such as a salary column to show how much that company is paying the user) do I need to manually create my own model anyway?

Comment: Yep, if you need additional columns, create the model yourself. Notice that you'll also need to change the association to `m.User.belongsToMany(m.Company, {through: m.UserCompany});`